# getattr() without 'class object'

Tags: python, mysql, flask

How can I use getattr without "Class" per se ?

So I have this situation: I have 'columns' that are asking mysql for specific data in a specific order. data is printed via flask/apache so that user has ability to manipulate this data. Now, From flask, POST methdd, I'm receiving changed(?) values and I am storing them in python attributes.I need to check if values within those attributes are same as in original data. Sure, I could hardcore it but I would like have possibility of change columns dynamically.

```
columns = ["username", "email", "admin"]
data = ("john", "john@snow.com", "True")

username = "john"
email = "different@email.com"
admin = False
```

Not sure how can I approach it ?

```
for i in data:
  if i == getattr(???, 'username'):
    print("it's the same")
```

or something like this?:

```
for i in data:
   if i == getattr(data, '?????'):
     print("it's the same")
```

Everything is within flask, I cannot embed it into the Class per se. So I don't have 'self' etc.
**If I could create class** I would probably make something like

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.columns = ["username", "email", "admin"]
        self.data = ("john", "john@snow.com", "True")
        self.result = []
        self.username = "john"
        self.email = "different@email.com"
        self.admin = False

    def test(self):
        for i in self.data:
            if i == getattr(self, self.columns[self.data.index(i)]):
                self.result.append("same")
            else:
                self.result.append("different")
        return self.result

Myclass().test()
```

['same', 'different', 'different']

Comment: Leave out the `"self." + `. The attribute is called `username`, not `self.username`.

Comment: thanks! I will edit question for clarity :)

Comment: If you can do something like `x = thing.attribute`, then you can also do something like `attribute_name = "attribute"; x = getattr(thing, attribute_name)`. ***That's all there is to it.***

Comment: @AlexHall, sounds great, but what would be the 'thing' ?

Comment: Literally anything for which it's possible to get `thing.attribute`. Just read the comment over and over again. I emphasised the last sentence heavily for a reason.

Comment: @AlexHall, I think i might be lacking of some basic python knowledge here. 'x = data.username' will not work as data has no username attribute, so still i am not sure what do u mean by 'thing'. Do you mind writing working example that would solve the very top situation in my post? much appreciated!

Comment: If "'x = data.username' will not work as data has no username attribute" then `getattr` is not going to help you. Again, as far as `getattr` is concerned, the comment above is all the information needed.

Comment: @AlexHall, thanks! you are probably right, but still, I don't know what to do with that information to solve my problem :)

Comment: Ask a new question that has nothing to do with attributes and `getattr`, because this is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I was looking for simple eval(). getattr() is designed for different purposes.

so simple:

```
for i in data:
  if i == eval(cols[data.index(i)]):
    print("it's the same")
```

did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Flask is *just Python code*. You can create a class and use that if that fits your use-case. Or, if you used [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/) to manage database-backed data you'd have classes and instances anyway (and get easier data updates to boot).

And classes and instances are not the only objects with attributes; modules and functions have attributes too (although you wouldn't store your data as attributes on either of those), and when you look up methods on anything, you are looking up attributes *too*.

Pick a storage, then either wrap that storage with an instance of a class, and use `getattr()`, or pick a different data structure and use the methods for that data structure to get at the different fields. A dictionary, for instance, would make it trivial to get the current value for a given name.

If you do stick to instances, then note that in your loop you'd want to zip your columns and `data` values together:

```
for name, value in zip(columns, data):
    if getattr(self, name) == value:
        self.result.append("same")
    else:
        self.result.append("different")
```

Note that you do not have to add `"self."` in front, the whole point of `getattr()` is do the same work the `.` syntax does.

You probably want to put your `columns` and `data` lists together as a *dictionary*:

```
self.data = {'username': 'john', 'email': 'john@snow.com', 'admin': 'True'}
```

because that's how you'd process POST data from a form anyway; that way you can iterate over the `dict.items()` pairs, or use just the `columns` list to access values:

```
for name, value in self.data.items():
    # ...
```

or use `dict.get()` to retrieve values, allowing for missing entries:

```
for name in self.columns:
    if getattr(self, name) == self.data.get(name):
        # ...
```

Comment: well, but I don't have a class so 'self' is undefined

Comment: @tmdag: you *do* have a class, did you mean *instance* perhaps? And if you don't have an *instance*, what data are you going to compare this with? If there is no instance, then you *know already* that all data is new.

Comment: @tmdag: and if you don't have a class at all, what are you storing the existing data in to compare with? If you have a dictionary, then just use `current_data.get(name)` to get the current value (or `None` if not set). But you used a class and instance in your question.

Comment: Peters everything is within flask. data is comming from mysql, going to www, and then i am getting data back. I want to update mysql ONLY if data from www (post) is different then what it originaly was. Ok, I don't have instance, I don't have 'self'. And all I want is just to compare those values, like in my example on the very top. How can I approach it ?

Comment: I've used class only as example (I've edited question just to be clear).

Comment: @tmdag: Flask is *just Python*. You can create a class. If you don't have a class, you have another Python data structure. Just use that data structure. And Python classes and instances are not the only objects with attributes.

Comment: ok, so here is my question - do I have to create class just to use getattr? is there any other cleaner way ? as it sounds over complicated just to make 'simple' task that i would like to achieve :)

Comment: @tmdag: you are rapidly veering into  *too broad* here. It depends on your data; if you have data in a list, use `zip(names, original, new)` to pair up the names with the original data *and* the new values. If you have a dictionary, just use `dict.get()`. If you have instances, use `getattr()`. Etc.

Comment: @martjin my problem is that i don't know which position of data list corresponds to which variable. Sure, I can pair those strings, but still i need to compare it with variable which is same as string. data is exacly as given in first example. Do you mind writing example code solving it? much appreciated!